# Function exported from TypeScript library doesn't work when imported, but works when included directly

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a monorepo with a three TypeScript applications: client, lib and server.

I would like to export a utility function from the `lib` app to use in the `server` app.

The package name for the `lib` app is: @labcorp/ngx-diagnostic-search-shared-lib

Example:

```js
export const sortAlphabeticallyByKey = (key: string): any => {
  return (a: Record<string, any>, b: Record<string, any>) => a[key]?.localeCompare(b[key], 'en', { caseFirst: 'lower' });
};
```

The build target for each TypeScript app is `ES2022` and I'm using TypeScript 5.3.3 in each. The `module` value is `commonjs`.

After installing the `lib` app in the `server` app, building works, but running results in:

```bash
> @labcorp/ngx-diagnostic-search-server@1.0.0 start
> node ../dist/server/server.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@labcorp/ngx-diagnostic-search-shared-lib'
Require stack:
- /Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/ngx-diagnostic-search/dist/server/hl7/proxy.js
- /Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/ngx-diagnostic-search/dist/server/server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/ngx-diagnostic-search/dist/server/hl7/proxy.js:32:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/ngx-diagnostic-search/dist/server/hl7/proxy.js',
    '/Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/ngx-diagnostic-search/dist/server/server.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

When I examine the `node_modules` directory, the `@labcorp/ngx-diagnostic-search-shared-lib` package is present, and its contents are correct.

Exporting enums, interfaces and types works as expected, but as soon as I add this function, it breaks.

If I simply move the function into the `server` app, it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?